# How to send HTTP response and receive HTTP request with web.py?

Tags: python, web.py

I want to build a web service, the service use Web.py, and want support script to send response and receive request.

```
    app = web.application(urls, globals())

class index:

    def GET(self):
        return "Hello, world!"

    def POST(self):
        webdata = web.data()
        #use script to send response and receive request.
        return webdata
```

But I can't find any idea to implement this feature, I want to known which API can be used in web.py or other lib?

Comment: Um. If you're using web.py right, that's basically what your current code should do. All web frameworks do is a fancy way of receiving HTTP requests and returning the results of your code in a response.

Comment: How do you assign the urls ? Have you try the http://webpy.org/docs/0.3/tutorial#starting ?